# Why can't I estimate the target variable when I apply a lag of variable

Tags: regression, stata, lags

I applied lag to the exposure variable to adjust for its previous time-point's influence.

However, the coefficients of the lagged variables are estimated to be excessively high, leading to the current period's exposure variable coefficient being estimated close to zero, which is the opposite of what I expected to confirm.

There is a related picture below (using STATA program):

`weibull _t cumul_dose_x_lag10_fac sex byr_fac age_stjob_fac styr_fac st_dur_fac occup_fac mtypecat sgg employ_status attained_age attained_age2 Lcumul_dose_x_l Bcumul_dose_x_l [pweight=invpnotc] if visit_lag10>=2, dead(_d) t0(_t0) hr cluster(id)`

[image]

**Red Box** expressed the coefficient of exposure variable that we want.
**Blue Box** expressed the coefficient of lag of exposure variable.

**Question :** Why is Lag variable's coefficient estimated too large to estimate the coefficient of the target variable?
What process should I take to solve this problem?

Comment: Ist the lagged variable and the target uncorrelated?

Comment: It would appear that there is massive collinearity or redundancy between the features. You need to share more information about your data. For example, is *exposure* the target or dependent variable? How close is the lag to the actual time of the target?

Comment: @MikeHunter
Exposure(red:cumul_dose_x_lag10_fac)  is independent variable and Lag exposure(blue:Lcumul_dose_x_l) is 1-lag of exposure variable. 

If the number of 1 was sufficient in the binary dependent variable consisting of 0 and 1, there was no problem in estimating the coefficient for the exposed variable at the current time even if Lag was used.
However, if the number of 1s in the binary dependent variable is very small, the problem arises as shown in the corresponding figure.
Does this problem occur if the number of 1s is very small in the dependent variable consisting of 0 and 1?

Comment: @Ggjj11 Yes, there is a correlation between lag variables and the exposure variable at the current time point. However, the correlation is almost similar between cases where the estimation was smooth and cases where the estimation was not successful.

The key difference between the two cases lies in the binary dependent variable consisting of 0s and 1s, where the number of occurrences of 1s is either sufficient or insufficient.

Comment: What is the meaning of *0 and 1*? What underlying behavior are they expressing?

Comment: @MikeHunter 0 means that no event has occurred, and 1 means that the event has occurred. I wanted to say the commonly used binary dependent variable.

Comment: Ok...having an independent variable and its lag is the source of the problem. Why have a lag of an IV at all? Usually, lags are of the target or dependent variable.